# Can't find module 'Firebase' error

Tags: python, firebase, pip

I'm getting an error when importing firebase into my python application:

[image]

However, I have the firebase module in: AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages:

[image]

I think I'm missing something obvious, but I have already removed and installed the firebase module using pip and checked if I can import other modules from the site-packages which I can do, so not where the issue lies.

Comment: Solution: Since I was using the Anaconda platform, all modules were installed in the site-packages section under the Anaconda Folder and not the global Python Folder as shown in the image above.